# How to use select option jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am not a UI developer, But I am doing R&D on javascript, I have written a code where each row is getting added, But I want to add a select option in a newly created row.

Below is the code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var i=1;
 $("#add_row").click(function(){
  $('#addr'+i).html("</td><td><input name='name"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='FIELD' class='form-control input-md'  /> </td> <select name='TYPE' ><option value='ORANGE'>ORANGE</option><option value='YELLOW'>YELLOW</option><option value='GREEN'>GREEN</option></select> <td class='deleterow'><div class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></div></td></tr>")});
```

Can we modify this , I want to get Select tag when I call #add_row function each time

Answer (score 1):

I could not get clearly what you want. But I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iranjeetverma/m4r9t8wg/) for you.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var i=1;
  $("#add_row").click(function(){
    $('#addr').append("<tr><td><input name='name"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='FIELD' class='form-control input-md'  /> </td><td> <select name='TYPE' ><option value='ORANGE'>ORANGE</option><option value='YELLOW'>YELLOW</option><option value='GREEN'>GREEN</option></select> <td class='deleterow'><div class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></div></td></tr>")
    i++;
   });
});
```

HTML will be like

```
<button id="add_row">Add row</button>
<table id="addr"></table>
```

Comment: that is  what I needed :)

Comment: @Ganesh Please mark the answer as correct if that's what you needed(click the check mark next to the answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've done for you.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#add_row").click(function(){
  var totalRows = $('.row').length, nextI = totalRows + 1;
  $('.rowContainer').append("<tr class='row'><td><input name='name_" +nextI+ "' type='text' placeholder='FIELD' class='form-control input-md' /><select name='TYPE'><option value='ORANGE'>ORANGE</option><option value='YELLOW'>YELLOW</option><option value='GREEN'>GREEN</option></select></td><td class='deleterow'><div class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'>X</div></td></tr>");
  });
  $(document).on('click', ".glyphicon-remove", function() {
  $(this).closest('.row').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add_row">Add row !</button>
<table class="rowContainer"></table>
```

Comment: @Ganesh : Hi, can you tell me if my answer is correct or not ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to separate you HTML in the event callback to handle easily each column and it's data.

I'm using in my example jQuery's `Append` and `Selectors` features.

Working example, take a look:

```js
// Waiti the DOM LOAD
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Setting the first row ID as 1
    var row_ID = 1;
 
    // Handle the button click event
    $("#add_row").click(function(){
      
        // Setting some templates to separate yout HTMLs
        var col_1_template = "<td><input name='name" + row_ID + "' type='text' placeholder='FIELD' class='form-control input-md'  /></td>";
        var col_2_template = "<td><select name='TYPE" + row_ID + "' ><option value='ORANGE'>ORANGE</option><option value='YELLOW'>YELLOW</option><option value='GREEN'>GREEN</option></select> <td class='deleterow'><div class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></div></td>";
      
        // Insertint an empty line
        $('#your_table_ID').append("<tr></tr>");
      
        // Get the new line
        var actual_line = $('#your_table_ID tr:last');
      
        // Appending each column
        actual_line.append(col_1_template)
        actual_line.append(col_2_template);
      
        // Rows count
        row_ID++;
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="add_row">+</button>
<table id="your_table_ID"></table>
```

jQuery's Selectors official documentation: 
https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

And jQuery's Append:
http://api.jquery.com/append/

Hope it helps